# custom tab title in android

Tags: android

i am setting custom title in my tab activity like this

```
    boolean customTitleSupported;
    customTitleSupported = requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
  //  customTitleSupported = false;

  //check for custom title supported feature   
    if(customTitleSupported == true) {
        customTitleBar();
    } else {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
        String title = prefManager.getTitle();
        setTitle(NAME + " " + title);
    }
    //Set contentview of activity  
    setContentView(R.layout.tabactivity);  

    if(customTitleSupported == false){
        setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.logo);
    }
```

Everything is working fine.But  when i make customTitleSupported to **FALSE** to check if custom title support is not there in sdk then it should call normal **setTitle()** function.
But if i do this  `customTitleSupported = false;`
i am getting following error

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title 

features
```

i am not clearly understanding the problem if custom title is not supported why i cannot request for other title features.If i doest not request for custom title then else part of setting icon and title works but i want to handle both conditions together.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You canot use other title features with FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, and you cannot turn off a feature once requested: check [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#requestFeature%28int%29)

You just have to use setFeatureInt(int featureId, int value) and provide a layout resource ID at "value". Check this example:  http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/CustomTitle.html

Comment: Thanks for answer.Then please suggest me what should i do if FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE is not supported,how would i set default title and image on my titlebar.